# continue in js program after finishing ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have a function with 3 ajax calls

```
var loadEditModalAddressData(){
     loadCountries();
     loadStates();
     loadDistricts();
};
```

I want from js to wait, until all ajax calls are finished.

Part of my code

```
loadEditModalAddressData();
$(document).ajaxStop(function(){
// functionality using requested data 
....
}
```

This worked fine, until I added extra features and figured out that *$(document).ajaxStop* is called after every complete request(or bunch of requests),not only in certain function scope, which mash up my code functionality.

How do I do that?

Comment: If I understood you, `.ajaxStop(function()` could store the requested data in an array. When you have all the data you need in the array, you call the function that use that data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The dirty way could be to use a counter in `ajaxStop` to make sure all three calls have returned. A slightly better way could be to add callbacks to each of your calls and to launch the treatment when the last is received.

However, the best way is probably to use promises.
If you use jQuery to do your calls, you can do stuff like:

```
$.when(call1, call2, call3).then(function(results){
     // your stuffs
});
```

Where the `callX` are what returns `$.get` (or any other jQuery promise).

Have a look [here](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$.when`](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) to wait for multiple defereds/promises. It's synonymous to the native [`Promise.all()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all).